# how to install Wompt

Tags: chat

I'm trying to install Wompt chat service on my web hosting but I couldn't find the correct way. I looked in the internet but failed to find a tutorial which explains how to install it.

Here is the GitHub link for the open source Wompt service:

https://github.com/Wompt/wompt.com

*Wompt is a web-based muti-rooms chat service. have a look at wompt.com

Thanks in advance.

Azam

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/Wompt/wompt.com) has a very clean installation guide:

Installation

Node 0.6

```
git clone https://github.com/ry/node.git
  cd node
  git checkout v0.6.5
  ./configure
  make
  make install
```

MongoDB

```
  wget http://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.4.tgz
  tar -xzf mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.4.tgz
  mv mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.4.tgz /someplace/in/your/path
```

Wompt

```
git clone git@github.com:Wompt/wompt.com.git
  cd wompt.com
  git submodule update --init
```

Wompt authentication server

```
cd wompt.com/authentication
  gem install bundler
  bundle
```